# Flutter firebase push notifications doesn't work onLaunch?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

it's been more than 72 hours for me trying to figure out what's wrong with firebase notifications! it's actually working on foreground and background but when app is terminated it's not working i tried a lot of solutions but unfortunately i couldn't solve it.

Here is what i have done:

pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--Firebase Notification-->
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
<!--Firebase Notification-->
```

Here is my code:

```
//--------------
//Notifications
//--------------

  var myToken;

  @override
  void initState(){
    final fbm = FirebaseMessaging();
    fbm.requestNotificationPermissions();
    fbm.configure(
       onMessage: (msg){        
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (msg){
        fbm.onTokenRefresh;
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (msg){
        print(msg);
        return;
      }
    );
    
    fbm.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        myToken = token;
      });
      print(myToken);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Can you try switching to latest dependencies ?

Comment: Worked, Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you so much